# Popular campos input com jquery

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Boa tarde,

Estou fazendo um formulário onde eu digito o Nome do cliente em uma tag input, apos preencher o nome ele faz a busca do banco de dados existindo o nome ele preenche o campo código, documento, isso está ok funciona perfeitamente, porem eu tentei esticar o código para preencher junto o campo input de estado e cidade conforme está cadastrado no banco, mas fica com status carregando...

Já vi em vários lugares e nao consegui adaptar nada ao meu código até agora, me ajudem please

**segue o código**.

```
    <!-- Nova Pesquisa -->

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[name='cliente']").blur(function(){


      var $cod_pn   = $("input[name='cod_pn']");
      var $doc_pn   = $("input[name='doc_cliente']");


      $cod_pn.val('Carregando...');
      $doc_pn.val('Carregando...');

        $.getJSON(
          'function.php',
          { cliente: $( this ).val() },
          function( json )
          {
            $cod_pn.val( json.cod_pn );
            $doc_pn.val( json.doc_pn );
          }
        );
    });
  });
</script>
<!-- Fim Nova Pesquisa -->

<!-- Nova Pesquisa 2 -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name='cliente']").blur(function(){

                var $uf_pn      = $('input[type="text"][name="ufCliente"]').val('Carregando...');
                var $city_pn    = $('input[type="text"][name="cidCliente"]').val('Carregando...');


                $.getJSON(
                  'function2.php',
                  { cliente: $( this ).val() },
                  function( json )
                  {
                    $uf_pn.val      ( json.uf_pn );
                    $city_pn.val    ( json.city_pn );
                  });
            });
        });
    </script>
<!-- Fim Nova Pesquisa 2 -->
```

**function 1**

```
    <?php
  /**
   * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
   */
  function retorna( $nome, $db )
  {
    $sql = "SELECT `name_pn`, `doc_pn`, `cod_pn` FROM `coh_client_completos` WHERE `name_pn` = '{$nome}' ";

    $query = $db->query( $sql );

    $arr = Array();
    if( $query->num_rows )
    {
      while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
      {
        $arr[ 'cod_pn' ]  = $dados->cod_pn;
        $arr[ 'doc_pn' ]  = $dados->doc_pn;

      }
    }
    else
      $arr['name_pn'] = 'não encontrado';

    return json_encode( $arr );
  }

/* só se for enviado o parâmetro, que devolve os dados */
if( isset($_GET['cliente']) )
{
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'coh_fin');
  echo retorna( filter ( $_GET['cliente'] ), $db );
}

function filter( $var ){
  return $var;//a implementação desta, fica a cargo do leitor
}
```

**funciton 2**

```
<?php
  /**
   * função que devolve em formato JSON os dados do cliente
   */
  function retorna2( $nome, $db )
  {
    $sql = "SELECT `name_pn`, `uf_pn`, `city_pn` FROM `coh_client_completos` WHERE `name_pn` = '{$nome}' ";

    $query = $db->query( $sql );

    $arr = Array();
    if( $query->num_rows )
    {
      while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
      {
        $arr[ 'ufCliente' ]  = $dados->uf_pn;
        $arr[ 'cidCliente' ]  = $dados->city_pn;  
      }
    }
    else
      $arr['name_pn'] = 'Ocorreu um ERRO!';

    return json_encode( $arr );
  }

/* só se for enviado o parâmetro, que devolve os dados */
if( isset($_GET['cliente']) )
{
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'coh_fin');
  echo retorna2( filter ( $_GET['cliente'] ), $db );
}

?>
```